# Locking a ToolStripContainer panel to only allow for one row of toolstrips

Tags: vb.net, toolstrip, toolstrippanel

I want the ToolStrips to remain on one row, and for the user to be able to rearrange on that row but not create additional rows. I tried using SetBounds on the LocationChanged event, if the user attempted to change the Y position it just sprung right back. However, this created some visual bugs, such as the mouse always jumping back to the location and the ToolStrips jumping around randomly (while dragging one, the other would hop around randomly on the bar...)

I also tried setting the MaximumSize of the toolstripcontainer panel, but it allowed the creation of a new row anyway (in which the toolstrips were hidden.)

EDIT: Its been a few months, still no answers...is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. Did you figure this out? You might want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403769/trying-to-add-a-toolstrip-to-a-toolstrippanel-side-by-side-with-an-existing-tools). I think it answers your question but I'm just surprised one would have to write a custom layout class to do what I would think would be default behavior for a ToolStrip.

Comment: Nope, never got an answer till now. I'll take a look at that post.